# How to autostart listener in Oracle

Tags: oracle, centos

after I restart the operating system Centos linux , the listener does not start automatically, so every time I have to type the following command:

```
lsnrctl start
```

how can i automates startup of listener ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add to your cron something like:

```
@reboot $ORACLE_HOME/bin/lsnrctl start
```